# Does such a matrix have to be orthogonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonality, orthogonal-matrices

$M$ is an $n\times n$ matrix with determinant $1$.

We know that if $M$ preserves euclidean norms for all vectors then $M$ must be orthogonal, that is preserves dot product.

But what if $M$ has the property that there is a basis of vectors $x_i$ with norm $1$ such that each $Mx_i$ also has norm $1$. Does $M$ have to be orthogonal in this case? This looks like it is true in $R^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no.  For instance, consider the matrix
$$
M = \pmatrix{1&1\\0&1}
$$
and the basis
$$
x_1 = (1,0), \quad x_2 = \frac 1{\sqrt 5} (-1 , 2).
$$